# Google Chrome - Bookmarked pages don't show URLs anymore on dropdown. Just the bookmark folder. That's very annoying! Is there anyway to restore URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, url

Chrome and other Chromium based browsers (e.g. Microsoft Edge) have a new annoying "feature" that hides the URLs of bookmarked pages on the Address Bar dropdown. Incredibly annoying! This is why I  am always apprehensive about new updates.

Here's an example:

[image: Image: No more URLs for bookmarked pages. How annoying!]

I dislike the change a lot. I need to see the full URL. Anyway to change this back to how it used to be with the URL displayed on dropdown?

Comment: Revert to older version. Report it as a bug/improvement. Pretty sure nothing else you can do, maybe it's possible to modify that with an extension, but I doubt as it's just an UI element.

Comment: Is there a flag that can be modified to fix this somewhere? Also

Comment: Also is there a more efficient way of reporting this as a ticket to Google Chrome other than Help -> Report an Issue? I've done that but I doubt it will get any attention from them.

Comment: I'd rather use Chromium's bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list Trying to use Google's forms directly is indeed not a good idea, throwing your complaint written with invisible ink a on a piece of toilet paper  into the sea would probably be more effective. As for flag, you could search for it, they're very poorly documented though and I doubt there's one for such a small thing.